# Unable to assign command output to a variable

Tags: command-line

I am trying to assign the latest file name obtained from the below ls command but getting some error, it would be very nice if someone can answer how can I fix this!

```
fn=`ls -lrt pur_bom_interface_daily*.log | cut -c59-102 | tail -1`
```

or

```
fn=$(ls -lrt pur_bom_interface_daily*.log | cut -c59-102 | tail -1)
```

Error got:

```
ls: 0653-341 The file pur_bom_interface_daily*.log does not exist
```

Note: `pur_bom_interface_daily*.log`
I am using `*` since there are multiple files starting their name with `pur_bom_interface_daily` and concatanated with the date on which they have got created.

Comment: (Have you are in proper directory that contains files?) Post output of only `ls -lrt pur_bom_interface_daily*.log`

Answer (score 1):

Your second line of script should work unless the pur_bom_interface_daily*.log files do not exist in your current working directory. To prove it try this example code block:

```
mkdir logfiles
cd logfiles
touch log-{1..4}.log
fn=$(ls -lrt log-*.log)
echo "$fn"
```

The results of the last command should list the 4 new log files that you made using `touch`.

The example code block should also work if you substitute the fourth line with:

```
fn=$(ls -lrt log-*.log | cut -c1-59 | tail -4)
```

...although you might have to change the `59` to a different number in order for the output of each line to be of a meaningful length (59 is the length of each line of output in the above line of code).

Answer (score 0):

Using backticks will assign all of stdout to your variable with spaces between each argument, spaces in filenames screw this up. To get first or last pipe into head or tail, try:

```
fn=`ls -rt -1 * | tail -1`
```

Option `-1` on `ls` is one file per line.
Option `-1` on `tail` is last line only.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I feel you have interpreted it wrongly
command below is returning only one line and it as expected when ran on commandline

Problem here is, pur_bom_interface_daily*.log is being treated as a single file name but what I want is all the files to be listed which have their name starting with pur_bom_interface_daily